# VBScript: Find a letter after the point

Tags: vbscript

I would need to find the first letter of an account entered in an inputbox.
Specifically, I'm interested in being able to find the first letter after the point.
For example, if the account entered in the label is "john.smith" I am interested in the vbs being able to take the "s"
Can you help me?

Comment: You could use `data = Split(username, ".")` to return an array containing "john" and "smith" then use `Left(data(1), 1)` to get the first letter.

Answer (score 0):

The comment posted by user692942 is correct (assuming there is always one, and only one, period in the account name, which is always followed by the last name).  Specifically, this one line will do it:

```
FirstOfLast = Left(Split(Account,".")(1),1)
```

Alternatively, this will also work:

```
FirstOfLast = Mid(Account,Instr(Account,".")+1,1)
```